# Reading JSON values with nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

So I am making an application in nodejs, which reads a json file and writes parts of the information to an xlsx (excel) file.

However in the json that I am working with, there are names of objects that contain a '-' in the name, example:

```
{
    items[{
        "example-object": "ex"
    }]
}
```

Now to put this object in a variable in nodejs, I would write something like:

```
var jsonObject = items[0].example-object
```

This works for object names that don't include an '-', but when they do I get the following error:

```
var jsonObject = items[0].example-object
                                   ^
ReferenceError: object is not defined
    at makeRow (C:\Users\Mathijs\Documents\work\api_to_excel\main.js:56:44)
    at writeToXlsx (C:\Users\Mathijs\Documents\work\api_to_excel\main.js:34:3)
    at C:\Users\Mathijs\Documents\work\api_to_excel\main.js:25:2
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] 
    (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
```

How can I get to the contents of the "example-object" without getting this error?

Comment: should be `var jsonObject = items[0]['example-object']`

Comment: `-` is not allowed in variable names

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access the property using the alternative `[]` syntax.  For example:

```js
// JSON
var jsonObject = items[0]['example-object']
```

Hyphens (`-`) are not valid in JavaScript variable names, but they are perfectly acceptable in JSON syntax.  If the variable did *not* have a hyphen, then you could do exactly like what you tried:

```js
// JavaScript
var jsonObject = items[0].exampleObject
```

Comment: Yes, I thought that was the problem, but I did not know the solution. Thanks a lot!!